# Match all entries { * }

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all entries like { * } for string (using Javascript). How can I do it?

Here is an input: `"#SD#{date};{time};{lat1};{lat2};{lon1};{lon2};{speed};{course};{height};{sats}\r\n";`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expression maybe:

```
var r = /{.*?}/g;
var s = "#SD#{date};{time};{lat1};{lat2};{lon1};{lon2};{speed};{course};{height};{sats}\r\n";
var matches = s.match(r);
```

Or if you want to strip those {} in results, you can run an .exec() loop to get a captured data only:

```
var r = /{(.*?)}/g;
var s = "#SD#{date};{time};{lat1};{lat2};{lon1};{lon2};{speed};{course};{height};{sats}\r\n";
var matches = [];
var match = null;

while(match = r.exec(s)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following regular expression:

```
var str = "#SD#{date};{time};{lat1};{lat2};{lon1};{lon2};{speed};{course};{height};{sats}\r\n".
var m = str.match(/{.*?}/g);
```

You'll find all the matches inside `m`.

Further references: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: You are using a greedy regex.  It will capture *everything* from the 1st `{` to the last `}` all in one group.

Comment: thanks @san.chez, I didn't know that site, interesting read. btw, I don't think this specific case will bring trouble to the OP. but thanks again (I agree with at least some of the points explained there..)

Answer (score 2):

For just the text within the brackets, you should be able to use this pattern:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("([^{|^}]+)(?=})", "g");
var testString = "#SD#{date};{time};{lat1};{lat2};{lon1};{lon2};{speed};{course};{height};{sats}\r\n";
var bracketTextArray = testString.match(pattern);
```

The `bracketTextArray` variable will be an array that contains the following values:

```
"date", "time", "lat1",  "lat2", "lon1", "lon2", "speed", "course", "height", "sats"
```

The regex matches every occurrence of one or more of any character except `{` and `}` (that's this part: `([^{|^}]+)`), that are immediately followed by a `}` character (that's this part: `(?=})`).  The `"g"` in the RegExp definition makes the pattern "greedy", so that it will find all occurrences.